# vue-advanced-cropper image croped sized is bigger than the original

Tags: image, vuejs2, crop

I'm implementing a system where user choose image, he must crop it before save; i'm `using vue-advance-cropper` plugin; all system is setted up but the result image sized is bigger than the original;

example: `i insert image at 307ko i got 448ko; i insert image at 40ko i got 206ko;`

is there any option that i missed to make the result lesser size than the original or is there not anything can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Abstract**

I suppose that the described problem has nothing common with the used library.

The most common reason that a cropped image size is larger than an original image size in the difference between a cropped image format and an original image format.

To clarify it. If you upload a `jpeg` image, crop it and get it from the cropper canvas by [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method, you will get a `png` image by default, so it's obviously will be larger than an original image in the most of cases.

That's because `toBlob` creates a completely new image from the canvas and it know nothing about original image properties. So you can't create **the exact copy** of the original image, including its size, by the nature of this approach.

The good news is that you can get closer to an original image.

The `toBlob` method has the following signature:

```js
toBlob(callback)
toBlob(callback, type)
toBlob(callback, type, quality)
```

So, you can set the same type and the reasonable value of an image quality.

**Solution**

There is the image uploading example in the [`vue-advanced-cropper` documentation](https://norserium.github.io/vue-advanced-cropper/guides/recipes.html#load-image-from-a-disc). I will show the full version of it bellow:

```js
import { Cropper } from 'vue-advanced-cropper'

// This function is used to detect the actual image type, 
function getMimeType(file, fallback = null) {
    const byteArray = (new Uint8Array(file)).subarray(0, 4);
    let header = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
       header += byteArray[i].toString(16);
    }
    switch (header) {
        case "89504e47":
            return "image/png";
        case "47494638":
            return "image/gif";
        case "ffd8ffe0":
        case "ffd8ffe1":
        case "ffd8ffe2":
        case "ffd8ffe3":
        case "ffd8ffe8":
            return "image/jpeg";
        default:
            return fallback;
    }
}

export default {
    components: {
        Cropper,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            image: {
                src: null,
                type: null
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        crop() {
            const { canvas } = this.$refs.cropper.getResult();
            canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                // Do something with blob: upload to a server, download and etc.
            }, this.image.type);
        },
        reset() {
            this.image = {
                src: null,
                type: null
            }
        },
        loadImage(event) {
            // Reference to the DOM input element
            const { files } = event.target;
            // Ensure that you have a file before attempting to read it
            if (files && files[0]) {
                // 1. Revoke the object URL, to allow the garbage collector to destroy the uploaded before file
                if (this.image.src) {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.image.src)
                }
                // 2. Create the blob link to the file to optimize performance:
                const blob = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
                
                // 3. The steps below are designated to determine a file mime type to use it during the 
                // getting of a cropped image from the canvas. You can replace it them by the following string, 
                // but the type will be derived from the extension and it can lead to an incorrect result:
                //
                // this.image = {
                //    src: blob;
                //    type: files[0].type
                // }
                
                // Create a new FileReader to read this image binary data
                const reader = new FileReader();
                // Define a callback function to run, when FileReader finishes its job
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    // Note: arrow function used here, so that "this.image" refers to the image of Vue component
                    this.image = {
                        // Set the image source (it will look like blob:http://example.com/2c5270a5-18b5-406e-a4fb-07427f5e7b94)
                        src: blob,
                        // Determine the image type to preserve it during the extracting the image from canvas:
                        type: getMimeType(e.target.result, files[0].type),
                    };
                };
                // Start the reader job - read file as a data url (base64 format)
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
            }
        },
    },
    destroyed() {
        // Revoke the object URL, to allow the garbage collector to destroy the uploaded before file
        if (this.image.src) {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(this.image.src)
        }
    }
};
```

This example will help you make the cropper result size pretty close to the original image size. You can test it online in [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-avanced-cropper-basic-jfy5w?file=/src/App.vue) with the lighter version of the code above.